# Run Scheduled Tasks once every 30 minutes

Tags: scheduled-task

How should I configure scheduled tasks in Plesk control panel to make it run every 30 minutes instead of only at a specified time? I use plesk 9.3.0...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use crontab: http://www.domaincheck.co.uk/plesk9-crontab.htm
And set it to 30 minutes, and to all the other fields enter *

Well, of course enter the command in the command field :)

Comment: Under minute, you should do `*/30` to run it *every* 30 minutes (12:00, 12:30, 1:00, 1:30, ...).  Specifying `30` will run it 30 minutes past the hour, every hour (12:30, 1:30, 2:30, ...)